# Helm get old versions from Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

We use Jfrog Artifactory to store Helm charts. Sometimes we get strange behavior: for example we try to pull chart 4.5.6+1300. We set "~4.5.6" in our charts, but actually we get version "4.5.6+1122". Older one. And only way to resolve this issue is to delete old version.
Have someone met such things?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the index.yaml file generated in the helm virtual repository is not up-to-date causing this issue. Have you tried to perform the [calculate reindex](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Kubernetes+Helm+Chart+Repositories#KubernetesHelmChartRepositories-DeployingHelmCharts) against the helm virtual repository and test it out if it works and resolves the latest package?